# Open Source Game engine for Visual Studio 2010 C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, game-engine

Is there any Open source game engine. I came across Axiom3d but i am not aware whether this can be used with Visual Studio 2010.

Are there any tutorials for starting building a game using a Game engine. I had searched internet but not able to find out a game engine that matches all my needs.

Plz give some details about game engine.

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.ogre3d.org/
http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/

Both are very nice to work with.

They both have .Net ports. I would start cheking out Ogre

Comment: Are they open source and free?

Comment: Yes they are both open source and free for commercial use.
For .Net http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/OgreDotNet

Comment: Do they support c# coding?

Comment: Do it needs separate .NET?

Comment: Not sure, checkout http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Installing+OgreDotNet.
They have a active forum, I sugest going there for more detailed help.